# How to make textarea fit its parent element's height in NG-ZORRO?

Tags: css, angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using `nz-input` textarea in 'nz-form' form.

I don't know how to make textarea fit its parent's height.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ur6mq?file=src/app/admin-publish/admin-publish.component.html)

Here is the status quo:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

I know what the problem is

[image]

If I directly set `style="height:100%"` for the two `div` and `textarea`, then I can get the target. But, the two div actually are not on my component's template html. So, I do not know how to fix this issue. I've tried to override the 'ant-form-item-control-input-content' css class, but it did not work.

Comment: It looks like your provided example cannot be edited. Could you create an example with editable code?

Comment: Based on techuila's answer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fin1te. Note: To set the styles for these 2 div, you need to either: change component encapsulation ,or use `ng-deep`, or set the style in `styles.css`.

Comment: @StepUp I've updated the demo link.

Comment: @XieSteven Did you have a look at the stackblitz I posted?

Comment: @David I've checked it. It also did not work. In my local project, I imported the `ng-zorro-antd.less` in style.css. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ur6mq?file=src/styles.css

Comment: your stackblitz does not work.`Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/dev/null'` The exemple I posted seems to do what you required though...

Comment: @David I've updated the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ur6mq?file=src/app/admin-publish/admin-publish.component.html

Comment: What did you try? I pretty much had to copy/paste the code from my previous link to make it work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zs6kcx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadmin-publish%2Fadmin-publish.component.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have this similar issue when using antd. My go to solution is always to use `flexbox` when I want to fit the remaining space of the parent height.

I could not give you an exact code sample from your code because the link that you provided is not editable, what I can give you is an example on how I did it by just editing it from the `inspect element` of the page.

**Screenshot Output**

[image]

First is change the `display` attribute of your `form` tag to `flex`, and set it's `flex-direction` to `column`.

**Form**

```html
<form id="my-form">
  // nz-input elements
</form>
```

**Style of form**

```css
form#my-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Next,** remove the `height` that you made on your 2nd `nz-form-item` (this contains the label content and textarea).

[image]

and also set the `display` of that element to `flex` and `flex-direction: column`, so we will be able to set the `height: 100%` properly with no issues on all the `div` elements inside including the `textarea`.
[image]

*This style is for the 2nd `nz-form-item` inside the `form` element*

```css
element.style {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I added a `flex-grow: 1`, because we want the 2nd `nz-form-item` to take the remaining space of the `parent` element which is the `form` element.

**Note:** Using `height: 100%` will copy the height of the `form` element, which we don't want that to happen and we'll not use this style.

**Now,** we want also to set `flex-grow: 1;` on the `nz-form-control` to take the remaining space of it's parent (which is the `nz-form-item`),

**And lastly** to directly set `style="height:100%"` for the two `div` and `textarea`, and we're done!

[image]
*You can see the styles that I set starting from the `nz-form-control` down to the `textarea`*

If you'll update the link on the post that is editable, I can give you a clear example how to do it. But for now, I can only give you this descriptive steps on how to fix your issue.

**LAST EDIT**

I've edited your code on stackblitz, you can have a look at the result [in this link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-safmq2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadmin-publish%2Fadmin-publish.component.css) :)

Credits also to `Sameer`, which helped me create this answer using `::ng-deep`. I wasn't able to add styles on the 2 divs under the `nz-form-item` tag without it.

**output**
[image]

Comment: Here's the demo: https://github.com/XavierMessi/ant-demo/blob/main/ant-demo.7z

Comment: I don't know how to use angular, I can only help you with css styles, can you provide an online demo?

Comment: Please check if this link is editable. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ur6mq?file=src/app/admin-publish/admin-publish.component.html

Comment: @XieSteven I've edited my answer, place have a look at the link I've edited.

Comment: It did not work in my local angular project. I will upload a total demo later.

Comment: In my local project, I imported the ng-zorro-antd.less in style.css. See stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ur6mq?file=src/styles.css

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ur6mq?file=src/app/admin-publish/admin-publish.component.html

Comment: @XieSteven It's now done, I've edited the link on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See if it helps, Add the `full-textarea` class to `nz-form-control` of textarea and below CSS to your respective component's CSS file.

```
.full-textarea ::ng-deep .ant-form-item-control-input {
  height: calc(100% - 110px);
}
.full-textarea ::ng-deep .ant-form-item-control-input-content {
  height: 100%;
}
.full-textarea textarea {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I directly set style="height:100%" for the two div and textarea, then I can get the target. But, the two div actually are not on my component's template html. So, I do not know how to fix this issue. I've tried to override the 'ant-form-item-control-input-content' css class, but it did not work.

So when you tried to override the css did you only override .ant-form-item-control-input-content? Or did you also override .ant-form-item-control-input? You said it worked when both divs and the textarea had a height of 100% but only said you overrode one of the divs in CSS.